# How to Populate UITextView with value from UIPickerView?

Tags: ios

How do I populate a UITextView with the value selected from a UIPicker View. So a user selects a category from the UIPickerView and the value is displayed on a UITextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the delegate of `UIPickerView`

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
 // Write your code here
 // yourTextField.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thepickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

switch (thepickerView.tag) {
    case PICKER_TYPE_A:{
        txtField.text = [arrayA objectAtIndex:row];
    }
        break;
    case PICKER_TYPE_B:{
        txtField.text = [arrayB objectAtIndex:row];
    }
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: The UIPickerView is not a datePicker but a UIPickerView with a value of strings which is retrieved from a NSArray string.